# Order by clause get_entry_list SugarCRM

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, sugarcrm

I am having issues retrieving a certain amount of products in order of the serial number through a SugarCRM SOAP API request.

Each request is retrieving the Products in order of ID by default. So I have entered a ORDER BY clause into the web request and nothing seems to change.

```
SugarCRM.get_entry_list_result_version2 result = SugarClient().get_entry_list(SessionID(), "Products", "products.status = 'Stocked'", "products.serial ASC", 0, myarray, link_fields, Convert.ToInt32(howManySelect.SelectedItem.Text), 0, false);
```

The Parameters are explained [here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/05_Method_Calls/get_entry_list/)

Essentially the third parameter the where clause works but for some reason the order by doesn't.

Most documentation is in PHP but my web application is written in C#.

Comment: ascending is default, can you try leaving off the " ASC"?

Comment: hey crowcoder i have tried that but it seems to still not work.

Comment: try not qualifying the field with the table, so instead of products.serial, try just serial.